# Messaging between chrome extention background,js to content.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to send a message between chrome extension **background.js** to **content.js**.

background looks like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tabs){
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {"message": "sample_msg"});
 });
},
1000);
```

content.js looks like this:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender) {
  console.log('blablabla');
});
```

manifest.json looks like this:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 1,
  "name": "Chrome Extension",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "/src/background.js"
    ]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://google.com/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "/src/content.js"
      ],
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "/src/popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "cookies",
    "background",
    "contextMenus",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "storage",
    "notifications",
    "identity",
    "identity.email",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking"
  ]
}
```

I read a lot and I don't get why it is not working?
can I have some help? direction? comment?

Comment: "not working" is too vague. You need to describe the exact sequence of actions and the expected/observed results. Also, make sure you've reloaded the extension on chrome://extensions page and the web page. Make sure to use devtools both for the content script and the background script: set breakpoints and inspect the variables. For example, your query doesn't have currentWindow:true so maybe it's the problem. Or maybe your active window is devtools which of course doesn't run your content script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**sendMessage** API seems correct, But It seems there is a problem with URL match.

Your content scripts will be only injected on `google.com` domain, As you mentioned in `matches` key in the manifest file.

> Open [google.com](https://www.google.com/) and check the address bar you can see URL
>   `https://www.google.com/`, so to make your content script inject to google domain you need to change your `matches`

```
"matches": [
    "https://*.google.com/*"
]
```

Also, change your **[onMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)** listener as below

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( 
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("Received message", request.message);
  }
);
```

Now go to `google.com` and refresh the page.